# Cache data returned by stored procedures?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, caching

I have an Asp.Net MVC 3 site. The following is the call stack

```
Web page/jQuery: $(document).Ready(.... Ajax calls... render the page...)
=> MVC Control methods
=> Entity framework 4.1
=> mapped store procedures (SQL Server 2008)
```

Question:

1. Where is the best place to implement cache?
2. How to let the page know that the underline SQL server tables have been updated?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the "best" way to do it but one way to do it would be to have an MVC controller action which calls to the db to check and see if the data has been updated. (You can do it by time-stamp.)

The resulting function will then retreive the data from cache or from the server.

http://davidwalsh.name/cache-ajax

The only interesting thing to note however; is that you should make sure that the call to first find out if you can use cached content is faster than not caching content at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add caching as close to the source as possible. This way more of your app could gain benefits from the improved speed.

If you control the code that is modifying the underlying tables you could invalidate the cache from there. You could also place a short timeout on your cache. If its a heavily used query caching it only a second could increase speed many fold. Make sure to test the performance gain so that you can tweak timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

For question #2, you may want to look into [Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx).  Setting everything up is a bit complicated, but that will enable you to do things such as caching until the data in your database has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to cache rendered views some specified time.

Let's say that you have page that is not updated often. So instead of hitting database on every visit you can store rendered view in cache. This is achieved using OutputCaching - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs.

Another way could be to store data.

Here again You can cache it for some specified time. In ASP.NET (MVC) it can be achieved using Cache object - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx.
Cache object let's you specify how long data is to be cached when You put it in cache. For example:

```
Cache.Insert("key",
   myTimeSensitiveData,
   null,
   DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
   TimeSpan.Zero);
```

Or you can cache until it is 'invalidated'.

Say you have GetCustomers and UpdateCustomer methods. In GetCustomers you check if data is in Cache. If not you hit the database, put it in cache and return. It is in cache until someone calls UpdateCustomer. In that method you write modified customer to database and invalidate data stored in Cache. You can just remove it. That way when GetCustomers is called again it will hit the database and populate Cache again. But remember that Cache has global scope and is accessible for many threads at the same time. You will need some synchronization code around access to Cache.